# count and sort according to column value in django query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

django model

```
class Report_Shop(models.Model):
barcode = models.CharField(max_length=500)
email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

above model multiple entries of one shop_name allow

how to count same value of shop_name  ???

shop_count i.e. number of  shop name (avoid repeated) -> example 3

s_name i.e. shop name -> 1.yyy 2.xxx 3.zzzz

no_reports i.e. number of entries of shop name

```
-> 1.yyy (3)
-> 2.xxx (11)
-> 3.zzz (5)
```

give me some advise for better response, thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Report_Shope.objects.values('shop_name').annotate(
   shop_count=Count('id')
).order_by('shop_count')
```

[Aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

```
Report_Shop.objects.filter(barcode='value').count()
```

and to sort you can add meta in your model to default order

```
class Report_Shop(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-barcode',)
```

or in your queryset with [orfer_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

```
Report_Shop.objects.order_by('barcode')
Report_Shop.objects.order_by('-barcode')
```

The negative sign in front of "-barcode" indicates descending order. Ascending order is implied. To order randomly, use "?".

Comment: i want to count number of shop_name (avoid repeated)

Comment: which ones have to be avoid?, because you can use distinct('column1', 'column2') like Report_Shop.objects.distinct('shop_name').count()